# Kendo Mobile - Simple button produces javascript error

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

After recently upgrading versions of Kendo Mobile, I get this error on a simple button widget:

```
<a data-role="button">Back</a>
```

Clicking on it produces the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined kendo.all.min.js:41
o.extend._mouseup kendo.all.min.js:41
arguments.length.t.(anonymous function) kendo.all.min.js:10
b.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:9593
v.handle
```

I am using Kendo Mobile v2013.2.910 with jQuery 1.9.1. My console window is blowing up with red text now... Any thoughts?

Comment: You're not alone, I'm having the same problem with v2013.2.923

Comment: Have you found a fix?

Comment: @Dean interesting you're encountering that error still. I upgraded to v2013.2.918 and the error is gone now...

Comment: @Troy After upgrading to v2013.2.918 of kendo.all.min, I started encountering this particular error.

Comment: @Alex Thompson are you working in Kendo UI Web? I only work in Kendo Mobile, so I switched over to using kendo.mobile.min.js and I haven't had an issue with this error anymore. If you're still having problems, there is a new internal build up from October... v2013.2.1002 - I would give that one a go.